# JasperReport - JavaBean Data Sources from official documentation

Tags: jasper-reports

JavaBean from official documentation:

http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources

"For instance, to retrieve the value of a report field named address, the program will try to call through reflection a method called getAddress() on the current JavaBean object. "

From my experience, I'm almost certain that it is not on the current object, but on all JavaBean objects (of a given type) that are passed as a collection or a list.

When I try to print an atribute of a specific instance of a bean, it prints all the values of all instances of that bean. Anyone knows how to pass this?

Answer (score 1):

How are you printing your attribute? If it is by putting a `textField` into a detail band, then that behaviour is correct. This is because the detail band is repeated once for every record in the dataset. If you are using a bean datasource this means that accessing the field `address` from the detail band will call `getAddress()` for every bean in the collection.

If you don't want an element to be repeated, move it to a different band. Or if you want to print the value only for a specific bean, add a `printWhenExpression` to your element.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I actually want to pass the values for a specific bean and curiously I was thinking about printWhenExpression but it didn't sound me as a "clear" solution. Do I have to consider another bean attribute that relates a child bean with is parent bean? or there is a cleaner way to use printWhenExpression? A more complete explanation of my problem goes here: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=92360#92360. Thanks again.